# Dashboard UI broke in Xcode 8

Tags: uistoryboard, swift3, xcode8

I recently upgraded **Xcode** version to **8**. Then, I run my project. 
My **Main.storyboard** does not appear very well and I don't know how to fix the problem. Please see my attached image. Please help me. 
[image: Dashboard UI Image]

Comment: Try using Xcode's Debug->"View Debugging" menu to see why things aren't where you expect them.

Comment: Hello bro @Phillip Mills, I don't know what happen my Xcode. When I open my Xcode today, my mainstoryboard UI is back to normal. :D Another problem I 'm trying to find the solution is here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488600/cryptoswift-and-swifthttp-issues-after-upgrading-to-xcode-8
Can you please help me the way of how to solve these problems?