# CryptoSwift and SwiftHTTP issues after upgrading to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, cryptoswift

I upgrade **Xcode version to 8**. I found these issues. 
[image]

[image]

Is anyone know how to solve these? Please help me.

Comment: Update your libraries.

Comment: I use latest version of   'CryptoSwift', '0.2.3',  'SwiftHTTP', '1.0.5' .